# What would be the fastest query to achieve this transformation from the Log provided to the comparative form needed?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to fetch data from a MySql Sales table comparing sales of each sales person.
My Sales table is like this -

```
 DateOfSale |SalesPersonId|       Value
>------------------------------------------
>20150324   |   300014    |  5600 | |
>20150324   |   300011    |  5400 | |
>20150324   |   300014    |  4900 | |
>20150323   |   300011    |  4100 | |
>20150324   |   300012    |  4200 | |
>20150324   |   300014    |  1600 | |
>20150323   |   300011    |  4300 | |
>20150324   |   300014    |  5200 | |
>20150324   |   300011    |  7900 | |
>20150323   |   300014    |  4800 | |
>20150324   |   300012    |  4900 | |
>20150323   |   300012    |  4600 | |
>20150324   |   300011    |  4200 | |
>20150322   |   300011    |  5400 | |
>20150324   |   300014    |  3500 | |
>20150324   |   300012    |  1800 | |
>20150324   |   300014    |  8700 | |
>20150322   |   300011    |  3300 | |
>20150324   |   300014    |  3400 | |
>20150322   |   300014    |  2700 | |
```

I would like to make a comparative report of all sales persons, something like this

```
              360012        360013      360014 ---- (SalesPersonId)
        ----------------------------------------------- 
DateOfSale1 |   Value   |   Value   |   Value   |
            |           |           |           |
DateOfSale2 |   Value   |   Value   |   Value   |
            |           |           |           |
DateOfSale3 |   Value   |   Value   |   Value   |
```

What would be the fastest query to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of `SalesPersonID` is known and it's relatively small, then you will use `CASE` statements. Something like:

```
SELECT 
    DateOfSale, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN SalesPersonID = '360012' THEN Value END) AS `360012`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SalesPersonID = '360013' THEN Value END) AS `360013`,
    ....
```

If the SalesPersonIDs are more dynamic then you'll have to get a bit craftier. Check out this article: http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html on how to get MySQL to do a dynamic pivot table. It's not for the faint of heart...

Generally, this type of data transformation is best left to your front end/display software since it's more of a presentation type of thing.